# I am trying to get an integer input from tkinter, but keep getting this error

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get an integer input from tkinter but I keep getting an error, but I'm not sure why.

The error is :

> value = int(enter_box.get()) ValueError: invalid literal for int()
>   with base 10:

My code:

```
enter_box = Entry(win,bd = 5)
enter_box.pack(side = TOP)

value = int(enter_box.get())   # this is the line that keeps having the error
value = (int(value))
value = ((value) -1)
results = (results[value])
print (results)
```

It should just get an integer from the users input that I can add and subtract from.

Comment: You're calling the `get` method about one millisecond after creating the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the get method about one millisecond after creating the widget. – Bryan Oakley

The way you structure your instructions needs to be rearranged to avoid this error.